# Accordion and Subaccordion opened in an another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a multi accordion in a sidebar built in Bootstrap 3.3.7 (see the picture and HTML code) I would like to keep open the tab/panel in another page (with the same sidebar) when I click the proper link.

[image: image details]

For a better understanding I want this: `sample.html#sample1`
     and
`sample.html#sample1#subsample`

```html
        <li>
          <a href="#sample1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Sample 1</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="sample1">
            <li><a href="sample.html">Sample</a></li>
            <li>
              <li><a href="#subsample" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">SubSample Menu</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="subsample">
                  <div class="accordion-group in collapse" style="height: auto;">
                    <div id="submenu">
                      <li><a href="sample2.html">SubSample</a></li>
                    </div>
              </li>
              </ul>
              </div>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </li>
```

I'm really new to JavaScript! It would be nice to handle it with jQuery.

Comment: I tried this:

$(document).ready(function () {
    var hash = location.hash;
   if (hash){
     $(hash).collapse('show');
  }
});

but I can't collpase sub element #subSample, any suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var hash = location.hash;
      if (hash){
        $(hash).collapse('show');
          $(hash).parents('.collapse').addClass('in');
  }
});
```